# In Python, how can I remove certain data from list to create a new one?

Tags: python, json, loops, python-requests

I'm pulling data from a json endpoint, which returns a list.

Some of the elements in this list, I want to throw out. I'm only interested in certain elements.

I'm pulling the data as such:

```
# Pull the data
url = "https://my-endpoint.com"
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'password1'
response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

The payload looks similar to:

```
[{
        "apples": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "oranges": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "name": "testing123"
    },
    {
        "apples": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "oranges": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "name": "foobar"
    },
    {
        "apples": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "oranges": {
            "value": 0.0
        },
        "name": "testing456"
    }]
```

Assume that the above continues on with many other elements, but with a different name. How can I pull all of the data, but exclude what I want?

From the example above, I would like to pull all data for names "testing123" and "testing456", but exclude the data from "foobar".

The new list is what I would iterate over to pull the data I need for my purposes.

Comment: payload is broken, please post a working one.

Comment: Build a list comprehension that has only the items you want: `[item for item in data if item['name'] in ('testing123', 'testing456')]`

Comment: Apologies, I've updated the json payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good deal of mismatched braces in your question, but I think I've figured it out. You have 3 (+ many more) dictionaries in a list, each with it's own apples, oranges (or other) keys, and then a `name` key. You want a list of dictionaries with the same structure as this one, just only the dictionaries where `name in set_of_preapproved_names`. For the sake of brevity I'll assume you have such a list of names called `OK_NAMES`:

`new_data = [Dict for Dict in data if Dict ["name"] in OK_NAMES]`

There you go!

If instead you wanted to eliminate all names with a specific pattern:

`new_data = [Dict for Dict in data if not Dict ["name"].startswith ("foobar")]`

That should work

---

Btw I know it's almost never a good idea to name variables after a type, I was just doing it for clarity here.

Comment: In this scenario, let's say there's a bunch more elements named "foobar123" and "foobar456". How would I eliminate items that start with foobar?

Comment: Oh so you don't want specific names, you just want to exclude specific names (or naming patterns)?

Comment: @hippe21 I edited my answer for you, same logic just different condition

Comment: Yes, my fault for not making that more clear. Still a noob on stack! :)

Comment: will give this a shot, thank you! Will comment and rate soon.

Comment: Don't worry about it, part of the reason coding in general is so hard is because it is all about getting something else to know exactly what you want, which is never easy

Comment: Levi thank you! also @John Gordon, thank you as well. This got me exactly what I was after. Surprisingly easy!